# Try to start my docker instance and am told container is in use, but then "docker ps" shows nothing

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.  I want to start a docker machine so I tried this

```
davea@blockshare_srvr:~$ sudo docker-machine restart odoo8
[sudo] password for davea: 
Docker machine "odoo8" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.
davea@blockshare_srvr:~$ sudo docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
davea@blockshare_srvr:~$ sudo docker run --name odoo8 -p 2222:22 -p 5432:5432 -p 8069:8069 -d yingliu4203/odoo8nightly -h blockshare
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/odoo8" is already in use by container "4ddc17305fc4df43bd2b42c07791d67817ff54d517550c581365245579c95967". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

It tells me the container name is in use, but when I check running docker instances I see nothing

```
davea@blockshare_srvr:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

What gives?

Comment: `docker-machine` manages VMs, not containers; it's not relevant here.  `docker ps -a` will also list stopped containers.

Comment: I'm not understanding.  "sudo docker run" would start a container and it's telling me there is already a container, yet nothing is listed using "docker ps".

Comment: There is a difference between a running container and a stopped container. After you run the container, it is stopping (which you likely don't expect|want). You may view it -- per @david-maze -- by using `docker container ls --all`. The command you are running `docker ps` (which is the same as `docker container ls`) only shows currently running containers. You may remove the container with `docker container rm 4ddc` (**NB you may use any part of the ID that uniqely identifies it). You may have docker remove containers as they exit with `docker run ... --rm ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all containers. (only running containers will be shown by default.)

```
docker ps -a
```

Remove the existing one.

```
docker rm CONTAINER
```

PS: To run docker command without sudo, you can add your user to docker group, (**but please be aware it will reduce the security!**)

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Comment: Note however that adding a given user to the docker group is risky! (especially for the main user account in one's personal workstation) because it implies any process of this user can smoothly get root privileges… cf. the doc [Docker daemon attack surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface). So I'd rather suggest keeping using `sudo`, and for the sake of conciseness, adding an alias `docker='sudo docker'` in one's `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks @ErikMD  you are right, I update the answer.